# WPF app : Inter-Process Communication for a multiple instance application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, pipe, named

I've developped a WPF composite application which is installed through MSI in c:\Program Files\WPFAPP1 on a Windows Server 2008.

Due to the targeted system environment constraint, several local windows account users launched the main .exe file (and thus start each one an instance of this WPF app) from a remote machine with a .RDP link.

Each Windows user is a known WPF application user (user access rights).

I would like to develop a .NET component to share data between users and provide a messenger-like feature : can I achieve this by using WCF service with named pipes please?

Thanks for your reply,

Comment: I think your question, in its current form, is just too big to get sensible answers. WCF can certainly be used to provide communication between applications, but it may not be the best choice for every situation. You haven't really defined your situation - what kind of data do you need to share? Is it time sensitive? Is it bytes/kilobytes/megabytes/terabytes? Are there 3 users or 3000? What are the security requirements? Are there restrictions on opening ports for messages? Other firewall related issues?

Comment: - Data : PDF File up to 2Mb
- 'Real time' file sharing (Lync look alike)
- 3 to  5  distinct users (1 WPF app instance per user)
- Security requirements : very low , I'm a dev sub-contractor and host machine is a laptop onboard a vessel in the middle of oceans or seas. 
- Port and message : I'm local admin of the host and can open any port on the OS host (DOS command, Powershell...)
I don't consider WCF TCP transport because the component would be running on the same host.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but far from an ideal solution. I have used named pipes for inter-process communication, but only for time signalling where the 2 processes had to be synchronized. It was not very reliable and had its weaknesses.

Named pipes communication requires additional threads to be running all the time listening for messages and the other processes would have to know exactly which name key to use to communicate with a particular process.

Basically, you would be far better off creating a client/server architecture using WCF and have the clients send messages up to the server to be distributed to the other clients. You could use a duplex channel like NetTcp or WsHttp to push messages from server to client, or have clients poll the server for new messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll be sure to try WCF duplex communication.

Comment: You can create a WCF service and host it in a Windows Service on the machine. Use some kind of database to persist any data.